# Does it matter if my SHA-2 is full Root SHA-2 or if Root CA is SHA-1 encrypted?

Tags: security, ssl, tls1.2

Does it matter if my SHA-2 is full Root SHA-2 or if Root CA is SHA-1 encrypted?

My CA is offering these two options and I am unsure to choose. We are building iOS, Android app, but clients should have latest Browser.

Comment: Do you mean if it matters if the root-CA you use is signed with SHA-2 instead of SHA-1? If this is the question then see [Why is it fine for Certificates above the end-entity certificate to be SHA1 based?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91913/why-is-it-fine-for-certificates-above-the-end-entity-certificate-to-be-sha1-base). Otherwise please explain in more detail what you really mean.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? It's not clear what you mean when you say your "SHA-2 is full Root SHA-2". Are you referring to the CA's root cert? If it is self-signed, then it should not matter if it is SHA-1 (or anything else for that matter). It's not clear what your CS's "two options" are though. In any case, if there are two of them, and one offers SHA-1 while the other offers SHA-2, then I can't see why you should not to go with SHA-2 to begin with.